# A simple SQL statement is timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

This is a very simple SQL statement:

```
Update FosterHomePaymentIDNo WITH (ROWLOCK) Set FosterHomePaymentIDNo=1296
```

But it's timing out when I execute it from the context of an ASP.NET WebForms application.

Could this have something to do with the `rowlock`? How can I make sure that this SQL statement runs in a reasonable amount of time without compromising the integrity of the table? I suspect removing the `rowlock` would help, but then we could run into different users updating the table at the same time.

And yes, this is a "next ID" table that contains only one column and only one row; I don't know why it was set up this way instead of using an identity column or even `select max(id) + 1`!

Comment: If you run exec sp_lock on the database once your web service is running you should be able to see what is holding locks on that table. That might tell you if there is more than one process hitting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an UPDATE of a one-row table takes a long time, it's probably blocked by another session that updated it in a transaction that hasn't committed yet.  This is why you don't want to generate IDs like this.

Comment: Yep, it was an issue with two transactions trying to run at the same time. Moving this statement out of its own transaction (why?!) into the original transaction that was already running fixed it.